# React (native) - inject custom components instead standard ones in 3rd party code/components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

For example i have library/package which exports some component:

```
function SomeComponent() {
    ...
    return (
       <View>
          ...
          <TextInput ... />
          ...
       </View>
    );
}
```

Is there any way I can use `SomeComponent` but instead of `TextInput` I somehow inject my custom `MyCustomTextInput`?

I know that is possible to create `SomeComponent` with `CustomTextInput` `prop` (it does not matter if `CustomTextInput` default value is specified like this or with `defaultProps` static initialization):

```
function SomeComponent({ CustomTextInput = TextInput }) {
        ...
        return (
           <View>
              ...
              <CustomTextInput ... />
              ...
           </View>
        );
}
```

What I need is easy way to tell to the whole application (all packages, all our modules/code) "where ever you see `TextInput` component use my custom `MyCustomTextInputComponent`". Is this possible in react/react-native?

Answer (score 1):

You can make index for component export package with conditions:
Look at example project:
Example: https://snack.expo.io/@djalik/thrilled-donut

index.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import {TextInput} from 'react-native';

const  MyTextInput=()=>{
   return  <TextInput value={'custom'}/>
}


const  MyTextInput2=()=>{
   return  <TextInput value={'custom2'}/>
}

let custom1 = false;
export default (custom1?MyTextInput:MyTextInput2);
```

and import in app where you need it:

```
import {MyTextInput} from './components'
```

Comment: Hmm I am not sure you understood my question. I can not change every js file where TextInput is used, I am interested  in solution  where I can just set in entry of my application that TextInput should be treated as my component . Or in worse case, I do not want to change SomeComponent.js to include specific implementation, I want to allow whoever uses it to specify his/hers desired implementation (without props solution, because that would be too much props setting all over the app)

Comment: I understood, all your app will import the textinput from some index file like in example and you can make in export conditional export  to what you call textinput or other  custom component  for all imports in the app.

Comment: But what if some package uses TextInput? I do not want to change node_modules files. Even if that package is my own how can I make it generic that someone else can use it also but with different textinput implementation

Comment: You can get and copy the package to local project and make the change as described before. I mean the package will be located in directory of your project and not in node_modules

Comment: I understand. there is no easy way. i supposed that. thank you for proposals, i gave you upvote

Answer (score 1):

What you want to achieve (substitute react-native's TextInput with your own component across the entire app) is not possible to do. You can't force library to render another component either (unless it specifically lets you pass that component as a prop). Solution here would be forking this library on github, making necessary changes to support custom component prop and using github link in your package.json file